# UISegmentedControl and adding targets

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uibutton

I'm sure this is an easy one for someone out there. I have a UISegmentedControl which I am using as a button (so as not to have to use the nasty default button) and I am having trouble getting the target to work....code as follows

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    //read.buttonType = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;

    UISegmentedControl* read = [[[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 50, 310, 54)] autorelease];
    [read insertSegmentWithTitle:@"Read" atIndex:0 animated:NO];
    read.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.3 green:0.3 blue:0.9 alpha:1];
    read.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
    [read addTarget:self action:@selector(changeFilter:sender:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [read setTag:1];
    [self.view addSubview:read];



}
```

and then

```
-(void)changeFilter:(id)sender{

}
```

for some reason, clicking on the UISegmentedControl does not fire the target method.

As an addendum, is there a simpler way to make nice looking UIButtons? I don't have access to Photoshop at work (although I do have gimp installed), so a way which doesn't involve image making would be good. I can't believe that apple didn't supply nice looking UIButtons in the UI, it seems such a fundamental thing to need?

Anyway, thanks for the help mis amigos.

thanks for the answers...I've tried the fix but it still doesn't fire

I now have

```
[read addTarget:self action:@selector(changeFilter:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

then

```
@interface
-(void)changeFilter:(id)sender;
```

and

```
@implementation
-(void)changeFilter:(id)sender{}
```

Note that the method is in the same class as the UISegmentedControl. Maybe I should just try using the Glass button API which was suggested, but my boss hates me using third party libraries if there is a way of avoiding it!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The selector is wrong. It should be, `action:@selector(changeFilter:)`, And change the event to `forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged`, as *UISegmentedControl* doesn't send any actions for *UIControlEventTouchUpInside* event.

Comment: Ah, that the ticket...thaks for all the answers.

Answer (score 5):

.h file u forgot to put this

```
     -(void)changeFilter:(id)sender;
```

then

```
change this 

 [read addTarget:self action:@selector(changeFilter:sender:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

To

 [read addTarget:self action:@selector(changeFilter:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

Answer (score 1):

The action will automatically send the sender so just try @selector(changeFilter:).

As for your second question, ios5 will help you out there... but I can't say much about that yet. For now, you can use some uibutton classes that people have made to easily make some good looking buttons. Here's one:

http://hboon.com/glass-buttons-in-iphone-apps-without-using-image-files/